# Verificar se existe um caracter dentro de um texto

Tags: php

Tenho o seguinte código:

```
if($_POST['Submit'] == "Enviar"){   
    $explodir = explode(";",$_POST['Emails']);
    foreach($explodir as $exp){
        echo $exp."<br>";
    }   
}
<form method="post" name="form">
<textarea rows="10" cols="80" name="Emails"></textarea>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Enviar">
</form>
```

O objetivo é que os usuários enviem os e-mails separados por ponto e vírgula: email1;email2;email3; etc... porém como eu faria para eliminar os e-mails que não contém ponto e vírgula? Ex.: email1;email2;email3,email4;

Comment: O explode já não faz isso?

Comment: Não exatamente, quando fiz o teste, ele colocou em uma só linha email3,email4. Estou pensando em verificar se o delimitador é ponto e vírgula, caso não seja, substituir por ponto e vírgula. Tem como fazer isso? Acho que dessa forma ficaria melhor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pode usar `preg_split()` que cria um array baseado em um delimitar é um expressão regular.

`[^\w@\.]` Significa combine qualquer coisa que não sejam letras([a-zA-Z), números([0-9]) isso é definido com `\W`, `@` e `\.` são exceções adicionadas.

`[^]` isso é lista negada ou seja não vai capturar os caracteres dentro dela.

```
<?php
   $str = 'email1#email2%email3,email4@lol@.com.br;_webmail.com';
   $arr = preg_split('/[^\w@\.]+/', $str);
```

Saída:

```
Array
(
    [0] => email1
    [1] => email2
    [2] => email3
    [3] => email4@lol@.com.br
    [4] => _webmail.com
)
```

Comment: Certo. Perdoe-me a ignorância, mas o seu código substituiria quaisquer outros caracteres por ponto e vírgula? Por ex,.: Se uma pessoa colocar email1Aemail2Bemail3@....

Comment: O delimitador é qualquer caracter que não seja uma letra ou numero, adicionei como exceções: `@`, `.` e `_`. @jose,Marcos

Comment: Entendi. Para finalizar. Para listar os e-mails colocaria dentro do foreach, certo? Ex.: foreach($arr as $array){ ... }

Comment: Sim, o retorno é um array, @jose.marcos.

Comment: Funcionou!! obrigado rray.

Answer (score 4):

**Estabeleça regras rígidas**

Não permita que o usuário digite os emails separados por algum caracter como `;` ou `,` ou quaisquer outros.

Como aplicar isso?

No formulário, crie um único campo onde será digitado 1 único email.

Adicione um botão para que seja exibido um novo campo. Nesse novo campo será digitado outro email. A ideia é, para cada email, o usuário clicará nesse botão de "adicionar campo", onde digitará cada um dos emails.

Ao submeter o formulário, basta receber o array e validar cada entrada.

Com isso, você elimina o processo de usar `explode()` e toda essa complicação.

**Para resolver da forma como está**

Caso queira continuar da forma como está fazendo, onde o usuário digita os emails separados por ponto e vírgula, basta que, no momento de resgatar o `$_POST`, faça um explode normalmente como já está fazendo.

Isso fará com que os dados formem um array.

Com o array em mãos, coloque-o num laçoi de repetição que validará o formato de cada string. A string que não possuir formato de email, descarte.

Se o usuário digitou vírgula ou outro caracter ao invés de ponto e vírgula, simplesmente ignore, pois a responsabilidade em digitar corretamente é o usuário, uma vez que não há uma regra rígida na entrada de dados, conforme sugerido acima.

Caso queira dar maior "flexibidade" ao usuário, permita que o mesmo entre com vírgula `,`, barra `/` ou ponto e vírgula `;`.

Nesse caso, a lógica é, ao receber o $_POST, utilize `str_replace()` para trocar tudo que for vírgula ou barra por ponto e vírgula.

Exemplo

```
<?php
$error = null;

/**
Verifica se o dado foi postado e se não é vazio.
*/
if (isset($_POST['Emails']))
    $emails = trim($_POST['Emails']);
if (empty($emails))
    /**
    Dados recebidos são inválidos.
    */
    $error = 1;

/**
Prossegue com as execuções caso não exista erros prévios.
*/
if (empty($error))
{

    /**
    Substitui vírgula e barra por ponto e vírgula
    */
    $emails = str_replace( [',','/'], ';', $emails);

    /**
    Explode o caracter delimitador ;
    */
    $arr = explode(';', $emails);

    /**
    Verifica se o explode realmente gerou um array.
    */
    if (is_array($arr))
    {
        /**
        Itera o array
        */
        foreach($arr as $v)
        {
            /**
            Verifica se possui formato de email.
            */
            if (ValidMailAddress($v))
                $data[] = $v;
        }

    }else
        /**
        Não foi possível montar o array.
        */
        $error = 2;
}

/**
Caso exista erro, exibe o código do erro.
Isso é para depuração. Obviamente, não deve exibir dessa forma grotesca ao usuário.
*/
if (!empty($error))
    echo 'error: '.$error;
else{
    if (isset($data) && is_array($data))
        /**
        Exibe o resultado do array final
        */
        print_r($data);
    else
        echo 'Nenhum email válido foi encontrado.';
}



/**
Valida o formato da string.
A expressão regular verifica que se a string possui formato de email.
Note que validar o formato da string não quer dizer que o email exista ou seja válido.
*/
function ValidMailAddress($str)
{

    $rule = '/^([0-9,a-z,A-Z,_,-,.]+)([.,_,-]([0-9,a-z,A-Z,_,-,.]+))';
    $rule.= '*[@]([0-9,a-z,A-Z]+)([.,-]([0-9,a-z,A-Z]+))';
    $rule.= '*[.]([0-9,a-z,A-Z]){2}([0-9,a-z,A-Z])?$/';

    return (preg_match($rule, $str)? true : false);

}
?>
```

obs: Não testei o código. Eu digitei aqui diretamente conforme o que foi surgindo a mente.

Comment: +1 pela primeira abordagem, nada de ser permissivo mesmo!

Answer (score 0):

Respondendo de forma direta, conforme título da sua pergunta:

```
if ($_POST['Submit'] == "Enviar") {   
    $explodir = explode(";", $_POST['Emails']);
    foreach ($explodir as $exp) {
        if (strpos($exp, ',') !== false) {
            $exp = explode(",", $exp);
        }
        echo $exp."<br>";
    }   
}
```

Note o seguinte trecho:

> if (strpos($exp, ',') !== false) {
>
> $exp = explode(",", $exp);
>
> }

A função strpos() encontra a primeira posição do caractere de sua escolha. Ela é mais rápida também, inclusive que expressões regulares ou até mesmo strstr(), segue o link da função: http://php.net/strpos

**Observação:** Sempre compare na busca com === false ou !== false, strpos tem retornos variados em caso de retorno falso ou vazio.